# How query/search for information from one Google spreadsheet to another spreadsheet using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a Google Apps Script to do the following: When I select a cell containing the name of a person in a spreadsheet (a spreadsheet that records sales, for example), and use a menu button to call the function, the script does a search (a query) using the person's name (or number of his document) in another spreadsheet that stores complete consumer data and that contains all the information that I need from that consumer to generate a contract or a payment receipt.
What is the best strategy to implement this search for information from one spreadsheet in another spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?
Do you have some script sample with a implementation similar to this? THANK YOU in advance for any help/guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event triggered by a cell selection, you'll have to use a menu item or a button to call the function or, if it is acceptable for your use case, edit the cell to trigger an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=en) event.

The 'search part' is actually very simple, the data being on the spreadsheet itself or in another one has no importance, it will simply change the way you access data ( [getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet%28%29) or [openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById%28String%29)). From there just get all the values and do a search in the resulting 2D array.

---

**EDIT following your comment :** here is an example of such a code that returns the range of the found cell (*and we get the A1 notation but we could* `getValue()` *as well of course.)*.

```
function test(){ // to test the find function with an argument, 'any' in this case 
  var result = findItem('any');
  if(result){Logger.log(result.getA1Notation())}else{Logger.log('no luck !')};
}

function findItem(item){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
  for(var n = 0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n].indexOf(item)>-1){ // this is a "strict" find, ie the value must be the entire search item. If you want to do partial match you should compare differently...
      return (ss.getRange(n+1,data[n].indexOf(item)+1)); // if found return the range. note the +1 because sheets have 1 index while arrays have 0 index
    }
  }
  return false;// if we come to the end of sheet without result...
}
```

Comment: Hi, Serge, thanks again for more one awnswer. Could you tell me how implement this "do a search n the resulting 2d array"? What's the best way to do this? A for loop wich iterates and compares strings? (the query string and the name field string?)

Comment: exactly, yes. You can take advantage of arrays function to find a match in each row using [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) method but the main loop would be a for loop to iterate the rows.

Comment: answer updated with example code. in this example I read the same spreadsheet but as I said it's just a matter of how to open the SS...

Comment: does it answer your question now ? or would you like more details ?